# Teradata :How do I erase teradata history (date/time, source, elapsed. rows, result, notes,length, sql statement,stmts,etc

Tags: sql, teradata, assistant

How do I erase teradata history (date/time, source, elapsed. rows, result, notes,length, sql statement,stmts,etc.. Is it advisable to delete history at all?
My log/history tab shows all the queries I ran since beginning and I do not want that..

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you ask questions based on code you wrote, not something that is potentially googlable. Can you post what you've tried already or your previous research?

Answer (score 2):

What's your SQLA release?

Depending on the release you can probably select the rows you want to remove and then press Delete. Or there's "Cleanup History" when you do a right click in the history tab.